# Пропадает интернет соединение через Wi-fi на ноутбуке с Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, роутер

Помогите пожалуйста:)

Мне выдали рабочий ноутбук Asus Vivobook с Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Доступ к интернету происходит через раздачу Wi-fi с телефона. Скорость интернета нормальная

Время от времени связь пропадает на полминуты-минуту, интернет страницы не грузятся, телеграм обновляется, конференция в зуме зависает. При этом, само Wi-fi соединение не разьединяется, и рабочий VPN продолжает работать(подкл через Ptitunl), не слетает подключение.

Проходят эти полминуты-минута и все налаживается само собой, как ни в чем не бывало, даже впн не разьеденяется.

При этом на моем личном ноутбуке Макбук Аир такой проблемы ни разу небыло. При одновременном подключении с двух ноутбуков - проблема только на рабочем, а на личном все хорошо. По этому мне кажется, что проблема не связана качеством интернет соединения.

Вот пример с терминала в момент сбоя, пинг не проходит:
[image: терминал]

Какие действия я предпринимала:

- отлючала-включала Wi-Fi на ноуте — не помогло
- отключала-включала раздачу/интернет на телефоне — не помогло
- обратилась к системным администраторам с работы, они удаленно подключились и обновили мне все программы до последней версии — не помогло
- раздавала Wi-Fi с другого телефона — не помогло

Сисадмины сказали что это все из-за того, что я раздаю Wi-Fi с телефона, что нужно кабельное подключение, тогда будет все хорошо. Но ведь на моем личном ноутбуке и так все работает и проблем нет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это может быть? Может ли быть проблема в нестабильной работе драйвера вайфай адаптера? или может проблемы с рабочим VPN ?

Comment: проблемный wifi адаптер как называется?

Comment: @PavelGridin MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network adapter. Надеюсь это то, о чем вы написали))

Comment: да, но ничего про него написать не могу, не встречался, посмотрите `dmesg` не ли ошибок от его драйвера

Comment: @PavelGridin к сожалению, у меня стоит ограничение и не дает выполнить эту команду, только сисадмины могут :((

Comment: `стоит ограничение и не дает выполнить эту команду` - дальше можно не продолжать. Слишком длинные задержки между советами и донесением проблемы до админов. Или кинь им эту ветку или пусть дадут тебе права. Так решать будем пол года.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал на `20.04` пересесть ради тестов, но железка, очевидно, не под полным контролем, так что см. выше.

Answer (score 0):

могу от себя добавить:
тот же ноут, та же ОС, проблема аналогичная или близкая, а именно нестабильная работа wi-fi адаптера, иногда вообще отключается wi-fi при том что сеть работает на других устройствах, бывает вообще отключается и не может долго подключиться.

посмотрите настройки питания вот тут `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

попробуйте поменять цифру в диапазоне 0-4 может что то изменится

**UPD. для меня проблема полностью решилась только переходом на ubuntu 23.10.**

Answer (score 0):

Схожая проблема на таком же ноутбуке.

Проверьте, стоит ли у вас програмка *tuned-adm*. Если да, выставьте либо на `recommend`, либо вообще отключите.

У меня отключение помогло, до стояло `latency-performance`.